# Access - Prevent Database Size Growth

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, filesize

I am using a MS Access 2013 light application that was developed by a third party. I did not do the coding/design/management of the project, but I am responsible for implementation for my team. I also do not have the option of switching to another solution, but I do have access to the vba code so I can make tweaks to clean up their mess.

My problem is this:

1. Set up application with my data (a-ok).
2. Run the built in, fairly complex third party macro.
3. For most cases, things are just fine... but when running it on a
   larger dataset the filesize of the Access file exceeds 2GB and the
   entire operation fails.
4. On fail, the process has to be restarted. For the same data set,
   it fails each and every time it reaches approximately 55% complete.
5. I am unable to complete my work because of this. :|

Solutions tried:

1. Compact and repair - Fine when it fully executes, but the issue is that it reaches 2GB while the macro is running and cannot be interrupted.
2. Splitting the database - Splits OK, but doesn't fix issue.
3. Attempting to trigger a compact and repair inside the macro during the loop - Fails because Access cannot lock the database.

Desired solution:

1. A way to prevent the file growth/bloat while the macro is running. Either through a compartmentalization of the process or through some other wizardry I am unaware of at this time.
2. A solution that does not require extensive reconfiguration of the underlying code. I can deal with inefficient - so long as I can fix this issue for this one instance (1 critical error in 44 runs of different data in the database.

Any help?

Comment: When you split the database, which file reaches 2 GB - frontend or backend? If backend, splitting to several backend DBs might be an option (distribute the tables to multiple files).

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears to be the front end. Total volume of data produced is fairly small, but the process to get the results is iterative. I think it is an issue with temporary data building up and not getting dumped.

Comment: Yes, I suspected that. I'm afraid you will have to delve into the code and find out which temp tables grow that much, and do some intermediate clean-up. Put a breakpoint or `Stop` command somewhere in the iteration, and check the database while the code is paused.

Comment: Thanks, Andre. I'm trying to think this through to figure out how I might do this. Complicating this is the fact that this code is really a loop of loops (Perform X, Y, and Z for each record for Q number of years). Once I trigger the 'STOP', is there a way to neatly trim the filesize back down without losing my "place" in the macro?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not in a position to make massive internal changes (_technically_ getting a copy with the vba module unlocked was a fluke and not supposed to be public, but it happened and now I have it, which has been good for fixing some other bugs). Recommendations are welcome. How would you do it?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to shift the temporary data that must be looped through into temporary database(s)?  I've had success with this approach for a handful of Access applications I've built.  ADOX is my library of choice - key classes you may want to investigate would be the [Catalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678060(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677529(v=vs.85).aspx).  [DAO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195520.aspx) can also get you there, and is purpose-built for Access.

Comment: You could try to - when closed - to mark the physical front end file as Read-Only. That will force temp data to external files but, of course, it will fail if the code tries to create new objects. Anyway, given the minimum efforts, worth a try.

Comment: Thanks Yllzarith and Gustav. I'll try the read-only technique and see what happens. Yllzarith - I think that the macro is writing data as it goes into an actual table instead of using a temporary table (Does Access even have proper #temp tables?). I haven't see ADOX, so I'll check it out. Thanks for the links.

Comment: Access doesn't have SQL Server style temporary tables, but you can emulate their purpose by creating, populating, using, and destroying databases and tables in code.  In my own applications I have gone the route of creating one or more temporary Access databases (depending on size requirement since each supports up to 2GB), create tables in them, and then link those to the application DB.  At that point I can use them like any other linked table. When I'm done I destroy the link and the temporary Access database file(s).

Comment: I think I see what you are saying. That's a good idea. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [compact on close](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Compact-and-repair-a-database-6ee60f16-aed0-40ac-bf22-85fa9f4005b2?ui=en-US&rs=en-SG&ad=SG#bm3_1) for easy **dirty** solution

1. On the File tab, click Options.
2. In the Access Options dialog box, click Current Database.
3. Under Application Options, select the Compact on Close check box.

**ADVANCED SOLUTION**

The other solution requires splitting the database.

After splitting you have another option.

Use the front with a sql server (check which version is suitable for you, I think the lite (free) version is enough to start with if you don't expect a hige amount of data)

1. Split the database
2. Install sql server (mysql or sql server express edition)
3. Create all tables in the sql server
4. Link the front to the sql server

Comment: Compact on Close is already enabled. If I could pause the macro, close it, and then pick up where I left off, that would work. The other option might be the only choice here.

Comment: what macro are you talking about?

Comment: macro's are not used while access is closed, I don't assume your writing a macro on close to compact and repair the database

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. There is a fairly extensive vba function/macro that processes data in this file. That function is causing the file to grow and reach the 2GB size before it completes. Currently, an incomplete run results in having to start over, which has the same end result. There isn't an intermediate step where I can close and reopen the file before resuming..

Comment: Not sure what you mean at this point, according to what you're saying I''m taking the conclusion that someone wrote a vba function and within that function there is code to compact and repair the database, but I don't think that is the case. To answer the question, no there is no intermediate option

Comment: It's in my problem statement in my original post. To paraphrase: I have a database. When I run some code written by a third party, the file size of the access database swells and surpasses 2GB before the code reaches a final "done" state. If the codes does not reach a "final" done state, then the results cannot be used. Restarting results in the same outcome each time. There is no code to compact the database (although the compact when closed option is already set - a feature of the file, not the code).

Answer (score 0):

I think davejal pretty much nailed this one.

If you have a handful of really large tables, you can put those into another Access DB, and make a link to those.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-another-Access-database-095ab408-89c7-45b3-aac2-58036e45fcf6

The 2GB limit is per DB.

Or, upgrade to SQL Server Express for free, and use Access as a front end to that SQL Server backend.

[SQL-Server Backend, MS Access Frontend: Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630555/sql-server-backend-ms-access-frontend-connection)

Here's a link to get SQL Server Express.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299